# checkbox always created with opacity:0

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to add checkbox in my mvc form but it's always created having opcaity:0 in css 
this my code where i add the checkbox

```
<div class="col-md-3 px-1">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Is Suspended</label>                                                                
     @Html.CheckBox("IsSuspended", false, new { @checked = "checked", @class = "form-control "})
   </div>
</div>
```

when i use inspect element in browser where i put my checkbox i found opacity:0 
but i don't know why it's been added to my checkbox or if I use something wrong

```
<input class="form-control " id="IsSuspended" name="IsSuspended" type="checkbox" 
       value="true" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was because I had given my checkboxes the class "tooltip", which has special meaning in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra piece of code in your project that is adding `style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"`. On my computer, I only show the `input` without the extra 'style'.

```
<input class="form-control " id="IsSuspended" name="IsSuspended" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

To find the source, use the `inspect` function in Google Chrome browser and in the `Computed` tab, click on a property to see where it originated. You will see the reason for the extra `position` and `opacity` styles.

Below is an example showing that an element's `border-right-color` was set by the `.form-control` class, which is defined in `form-less` file. You can do the same for `position` and `opacity`.

[image: Inspect]

Comment: i found there's extra tag in my code   where did it come from `<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>`

Comment: Nice job. If I was able to help you, you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem that I'm using js library called icheck in my js files 
i deleted it and now it's fine